# How can I query 60 timestamp in a SQL?

Tags: mysql

Suppose I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE `monitor_index_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `index_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `index_time` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `value` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I will save data in this table every 10 minutes with the timestamp store in index_time column.

The value of index_time is like 1559540700000

Now I have to query data last 60 days at the moment (for example 2019-06-19 02:10:00, How can I write this SQL in one line? Like, I want to get the data at today, yesterday, and the day before yesterday at 02:10:00.

I have searched a lot about SQL format() function, but still do not know how to do it.

I maybe not express my question clearly. I was wondering I stored a lot of data in database. But I want to just query such as:

```
2019-06-20 02:00:00
2019-06-19 02:00:00
2019-06-18 02:00:00
...
2019-05-18 02:00:00
```

How can I write this in one SQL?

Edit:

First thank you for providing me the UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY). But I still cannot figure out how to query 60 times.

Comment: Why don't you use a proper datatype like datetime or timestamp?

Comment: @tombom Actually, the table structure is not defined by me.

Comment: If you could change the table structures, you might want to look at [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). Since you can't change the table structure, I didn't write this up as an answer, but you should be able to get an idea of what I'm driving at [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e8f2c0b7ab57f225d46f700c07addfe3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE index_time > 1000 * UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)
```

The `1000 *` is because you seem to have milliseconds.

`NOW()` is the current time to the second.  `NOW(3)` is current time to the millisecond (probably overkill).  `CURDATE()` is midnight of this morning.

If, instead of `BIGINT`, you used `DATETIME` or `DATETIME(3)` or `TIMESTAMP(3)`, you could avoid needing any conversion routines.

Answer (score 2):

You need a conversion function to translate "sensible" timestamps into [what look to me like] Unix timestamps.  Using that, you can write the query [almost] as you would normally:

```
select * 
from monitor_index_data
where index_time >= unix_timestamp( '2019-06-19 02:10:00' );
```

Comment: I have inserted a lot of data in this table, but I want to just query 60 days' data of this moment.

Comment: So change the timestamp literal to go back to the point you want to query from, something like '2019-04-20 02:10:00' or use SQL functions to calculate it dynamically, as in DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 60 DAY ).